# How do I get ggplot to produce a plot in python

Tags: python, ggplot2

I'm familiar with ggplot in R. Using RStudio, a plot would be produced in the bottom right window.

If I try to run a python program to generate a ggplot, nothing happens in my terminal. The code runs without error, but nothing is produced. Am I missing something?

Matplot seems to work fine, and produces a plot.

I'm using Fedora 32, python 3.8, and ggplot found on pip.

```
from ggplot import *
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv(
    "path-to-data")
g = ggplot(data,  aes('TIMEn', 'ENTRIESn_hourly')) + \
    geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="lm")
g
```

UPDATE: OK, I think part of the problem was the size of the data in the csv. I can get a plot produced now, but only if I run the code line by line in terminal. Nothing will be produced if I run "python filename.py"

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got something to work. I just used the `.save()` method to save the plot in a working directory. That seemed to fix everything.